# jquery dialog capture form data from external site

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would you capture form data from a dialog window on your website that is going to an external website?  For example, the dialog loads the website www.google.com.  I want to capture the text typed when the when the user searches for something.  If that's not possible, is there a way to capture the key strokes from the dialog window?

Comment: It's for a project I'm working on.  It would be fully disclosed from our website that we are capturing this information to save them time when they are filling out our forms.  It's not unethical or illegal when it's fully disclosed.

Answer (score -1):

That depends on the site, if they have an API.
Though I must tell you, you are talking about spying on people using internet,that's illegal and unethical.

Comment: It's for a project I'm working on. It would be fully disclosed from our website that we are capturing this information to save them time when they are filling out our forms. It's not unethical or illegal when it's fully disclosed.